# Is there a way to use OpenVidu in Safari version 8+?

Tags: ios, react-native, mobile-safari, openvidu

I'm getting this [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVaZd.png) when I try to use [OpenVidu](https://openvidu.io/) on my React Native iOS app, but the OpenVidu [documentation](https://docs.openvidu.io/en/stable/releases/#new-supported-browsers-in-ios) says that it supports Safari latest versions. Does anyone knows which one is the truth and what I might do to solve this issue (considering that Im using Web View to render OpenVidu)?